# linux TCshell script

Tags: linux, shell

i have written a simple shell script for TCsh shell .the code is just to take an input from the user and then run something based on the input.I have used switch case for this but my PROBLEM is whatever i enter it ends up executing the default case.

```
#!bin/tcsh
echo "creating workdir = setup "
echo "extracting = extract"
echo "creating setups= create "
echo "validate = all(for running all validation),ve ,fa ,annotate ,Lib, CDL"
set user_input = "$<"
echo "entered string is -" $user_input
switch (user_input)
case setup:
./validateSource -sc -setup -check ve fa annotate Lib CDL -source source -library     library -reference reference
breaksw
case extract:
./validateSource -sc -extract -check ve fa annotate Lib CDL -source source -library library -reference reference
breaksw
case (create):
./validateSource -sc -create -check ve fa annotate Lib CDL -source source -library library -reference reference -workdir workdir_nowb_EDA_7p2
breaksw
case (all):
./validateSource -sc -validate -check ve fa annotate Lib CDL -workdir workdir_nowb_EDA_7p2 -force
breaksw
case (ve):
./validateSource -sc -validate -check ve -workdir workdir_nowb_EDA_7p2 -force
breaksw
case (fa):
./validateSource -sc -fa -check ve -workdir workdir_nowb_EDA_7p2 -force
breaksw
case (annotate):
./validateSource -sc -validate -check annotate -workdir workdir_nowb_EDA_7p2 -force
breaksw
case (Lib):
./validateSource -sc -validate -check Lib -workdir workdir_nowb_EDA_7p2 -force
breaksw
case (CDL) :
./validateSource -sc -validate -check CDL -workdir workdir_nowb_EDA_7p2 -force
breaksw 
default :
echo "wrong string entered"
endsw
```

Comment: The `t` of `tcsh` means terminal. A `tcsh` script makes no sense, you can simply use `csh` with the same syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Read the famous [csh considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) paper.

Consider using another shell. The most portable is to restrict yourself to [posix shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) (with [`dash`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell), [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/)  or even [`zsh`](http://www.zsh.org/) providing good compliance when correctly configured).

My preference go to `zsh`.

To debug your shell script, try passing `-v` and `-x` to the shell, e.g. `/bin/tcsh -x -v yourshellscript`

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use csh, (you should seriously consider @Basile Starynkevitch's advice), there's a couple of things wrong with your script.

First, you're missing a / in the first line:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
```

And you're switch statement is wrong, you need a $ in front of your variable:

```
switch ($user_input)
```

You can probably take it from here. Note that if you type `create`, it won't match `(create)`, which is what you have in your case statement.